# How to Check SMTP Server is up and running

Tags: c#, smtp

I am currently checking SMTP Server is up and running before sending mail using below code :

```
 public static bool ValidateSMTPServer()
        {
            bool valid = false;
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient smtpTest = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            try
            {
                smtpTest.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServerName"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PortNumber"]));
                return true;

            }
            catch
            {
                return valid;
            }
            finally
            {
                smtpTest.Close();
            }

        }
```

But the problem is it takes around 25 seconds to respond back if server is not running..which decrease my page performance. I do this on Click of button before sending mails.
Is there any better approach than this ? or i can do some changes to existing code.

And in case of server is not running it goes to catch part and i make my flag return false which means smtp is down..is there any way i can get the status code that server is not running...SMTPException is also i tried..if i use the same program breaks.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- You can check in the background - and store that in a static variable. Do it in a loop and you avoid the wait.
- The setup could be changed using a local SMTP Server to take them from a drop folder. Lots of pseudo negatives but at least you can send when the server is down / overloaded / starting. I personally prefer that. I used that way for ages - sadly MS slowly is retiring their SMTP service. It is great if a server can just drop emails in a folder and then they get sent over time.

In a larger setup the SMTPO servre should not be down because it is a cluster behind a load balancer ;)

Comment: I understand your point and i am doing the same way...my intention of above scenario is if server is down i should notify the user...SMTP Server is down..they can try later or after some time...